# How to show element once in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to loop through a list order by price and as soon as the price is not there then I show a message with unavailable but I don't want to show it for each empty element. I'm using angular 1.2

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy: 'cost'">

  <div ng-if="cost == 0 and not already shown">Sorry the following are unavailable</div>
  <div>...my item here...</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Do you also need to list the "unavailable"?

Comment: yup. just with the comment above the list that they are unavailable

Comment: and I'm trying to not have to duplicate the html for ... my item here...

Comment: I've tried something similar but was hoping their was some ng-once directive or something. I will try it when i check that branch back out when i'm done with my current task. If it doesn't work I may just print it every time cost == 0 then use css :first-child syntax to unhide the one i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best way I could find to get it done.

Markup

```
<div class="sold-out-message" ng-if="displaySoldOutMessage(item)">Sorry, sold out</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.firstSoldOutItemId = false;
$scope.displaySoldOutMessage = function(item) {
   if ( item.cost ) return false;

   $scope.firstSoldOutItemId = $scope.firstSoldOutItemId || item.id;

   return item.id == $scope.firstSoldOutItemId;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally display two spans - one if it's `0` (your 'not available' message) and another for anything else.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="d in newData track by $index">
    <span ng-show="d > 0">{{d}}</span>
    <span ng-show="d === 0">Not Available</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The data can be passed through a function to pull all the `0` after the first one:

```
  $scope.data = [1,2,3,0,1,0,0,1,0,2]
  $scope.pullDupes = function(array) {
    var newArray = [];
    var zero;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] !== 0) {
        newArray.push(array[i])
      }
      if (array[i] === 0 && !zero) {
        zero = true;
        newArray.push(array[i])
      } 
    }
    return newArray;
  }
  $scope.newData = $scope.pullDupes($scope.data);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hj14H7QcwfnntzNrs1P0?p=preview)

Comment: The request was to show only a single "Not available" message if there is one or more items without cost

Comment: Yes, I didn't catch exactly what he was asking.

Comment: I believe it accurately addresses the OP now.

Comment: well, previously I downvoted because it didn't address the question. But now, this is downright bad advice - you essentially have an expensive for loop firing on every digest, not to mention that the OP didn't want to de-dupe items - just to show a single message for items with one property of 0

Comment: He didn't say he didn't want to either.  It's one way of addressing it.  It's not tampering with the original data, just displaying it.
The for loop may or may not be a big deal though, depending on what he is doing.
Nevertheless, I rewrote it so it isn't firing on every $digest.

Comment: I'll remove the downvote... I still think you missed the OP's point - he actually wants to show all the items with zero cost - but I'll let him make it

Comment: Thanks, though that is what I understood him to be saying - "then I show a message with unavailable but I don't want to show it for each empty element" - meaning he only want's to show that unavailable message one time.  It is possible the question could be further clarified.  As you said, he can decide.

Answer (score 1):

You can show only the first message see here :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy: 'cost'">
    <div style="color:red" ng-show="item.cost == 0 && $first">Message Goes Here</div>
    <hr>
    <div>{{item.name}} - Price : {{item.cost}}</div>
</div>
```

and here is a plunker for it :

http://plnkr.co/edit/RwZPZp9rFIChWxqF71O7?p=preview

also the `ng-if` you are using it wrong you need to do it like this `item.cost` for the next time

Cheers !

Comment: This looks great except I need the available ones first so when I order by cost by the time i get to one that is unavailable it is not the first item

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use $scope.$whatch with a boolean variable like this:

```
   <div ng-model="actualItem" ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy: 'cost'">
             <div ng-if="cost == 0 && oneMessage == true">Sorry the following are unavailable</div>
                  <div>...my item here...</div>
             <div>
   </div>
```

And in your controller you look at actualItem :

```
      $scope.oneMessage = false;
      var cpt = 0; // if 1 so you stop to send message
      $scope.$watch('actualItem',function(value){
    if(value.cost == 0 && $scope.oneMessage == false && cpt < 1) 
      // i don't know what is your cost but value is your actual item 
    {
       $scope.oneMessage = true;
       cpt++;
    } 
    else if($scope.oneMessage == true)
      {
         $scope.oneMessage == false;
      }
  });
```

I am not sure about this but you can try it. It's certainly not the best way.